# Microsoft outlook sync contacts + settings between multiple computers

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Basically I have looked for this for some time now. I hope it is not a duplicate. I have a PC at work and another PC at home. I don't want to keep outlook completely sync in both, but just the contacts and settings if possible. The former is much more important for me.

By contacts I mean: *if I add a contact or a contact group at work, I need to see it at home*.

By settings I mean: *if I create a new category or tag at work, I need to see it at home*.

Is there any free solution for this? Sharing a file in the cloud like `dropbox`, `ubuntuone`, etc

Comment: Something like `Active Exchange` works for something like this.

Comment: @Ramhound, Could you elaborate a bit more on that (Maybe a quick answer). Does it mean Microsoft exchange server?

Comment: I assumed since your using `Outlook 2010` that you were using an `Exchange` on both ends.  I know nothing about what is and is not possible in a situation like this.  I just know that `Active Exchange Sync` allows you to sync contacts across multiple devices.

Comment: @Ramhound, OK thanks. Yes I am using `Outlook 2010` but I am not using any `Exchange` at the moment. I will do some research on this.

Comment: What are you using if not Exchange?

Comment: @Ramhound, I am not using Exchange. I just have a couple of IMAP email accounts and local contacts.

Comment: There are add-ons for Outlook that might offer something like this. Since your not using Exchange `Active Exchange Sync` wouldn't do much for you.  Of course if you are using Yahoo, Hotmail, Google Mail you can easily import/export the contacts between the accounts.